# Meta-analysis of previous published dataset - who to include as coauthor?

Tags: authorship, data, meta-analysis

I recently published a paper, which includes a link to a data repository in which that data is available. Now, with other researchers, we are combining our datasets in a meta-analysis.

I was wondering what the etiquette was regarding inclusion of the co-authors of the first paper (who are not involved in the meta-analysis, but were integral to collecting my initial dataset).

I think I should send them a courtesy email saying "I'm doing meta-analysis with these other people using our dataset that can be downloaded by anyone".

Should I do more (beyond this, and an acknowledgement in the paper)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited to add some paragraph blocks which maybe will make the question easier to read, but I don't know what made someone choose the "please clarify your specific problem" in review; the problem asked about seems quite obvious and clear to me.

Answer (score 4):

I think the applicable principle is that authorship isn't transitive. If someone doesn't contribute directly to a paper they aren't an author, but may need acknowledgement as you suggest.

But it is a good idea, as you also may be suggesting, that you offer those others the opportunity to participate and thus become authors. I realize that might not be your actual intention, but suggest you stay open to offers.